# Wordpress site generates JQuery code in excerpt when you press Facebook Share button HELP!

Tags: facebook, wordpress

i have been facing what i believe is a JQuery issue that has been driving me absolutely nuts that no one can seem to solve. I was wondering if you might be able to help me out, it is probably a simple thing.

I have created a few websites using Wordpress and when the user clicks on the Facebook share button an error code pops up where the excerpt summary should appear every single time, i cannot figure out what it is! Example can be found here just click the "Facebook Share" button to see what i am talking about.

http://jaewong.com/ashkon/2011/06/19/post-2-video-hidden/

Sample error code appearing in Facebook excerpt

> ';         dtsl.front.init();     }); 
>   jQuery(window).load(function(){
>   jQuery(".hentry").imagefit();      });
>   .wp-polls .pollbar {     margin: 1px; 
>   font-size: 6px;     line-height: 8px; 
>   height: 8px;     background-image:
>   url('http://jaewong.com/ashkon/wp-content/plugins/wp-polls/images/defau

Hope you can help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can put whatever you want as excerpt using the facebook og tag. just place this tag in the `<head>` tag of your template.

```
<meta property="og:description"
          content="Your excerpt here"/>
```

Check this page for customizing the content of the share link. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

*Update:*

it seems that your site is OK. I've checked that page with URL linter, http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/

Facebook has cached some content of your site which is appearing as error. I think it will be ok after some time

Comment: Thanks thats a great start, I am almost there. Instead of a custom excerpt I want it to be an automatically generated excerpt from the blog post, what would the code be? Thanks!

Comment: this blog post might help you, [Blog Article](http://www.michelem.org/2008/07/11/wordpress-dynamic-meta-description-and-keywords-howto/).

Comment: Looks like the Facebook Lint worked on a couple posts but still gives the JQuery code in the excerpt when sharing. =( It appears to not like the featured images or images in general.